# How to prevent dev users from using Allow filtering in cassandra database

Tags: cassandra

I have dev users querying prod database and use ALLOW FILTERING in their queries which is causing timeout error in the prod applications. I am checking if we can restrict dev users from using ALLOW filtering using restrictions at userid level.

I have gone through almost all the existing Stack Overflow questions on ALLOW filtering. But my question in on how to prevent non admin users from querying using "ALLOW FILTERING".

So far I have created non admin id and assigned read only access to certain keyspaces but they are still able to do ALLOW FILTERING on their queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer to this is you can't.

[CASSANDRA-8303](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8303) was raised to add a capability limitation framework that would allow `ALLOW FILTERING` to be disabled for groups of users but it is still marked as open.

Comment: I will keep track of the above 8303 ticket and hopefully this could be available soon in a new release of Cassandra.